# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean @Value("${com.test.isTestEnable")

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting 
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **

I believe this happens due to missing spring place holder config. But I have the bean initialised in application context and still getting this error. Can any one help me out??

```
    @Value("${com.test.isTestEnable")
    public Boolean isTestEnable;
```

Spring Properties Class

```
public class SpringPropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static HashMap<String, String> systemPropertiesMap;

    private int springSystemPropertiesMode = SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK;

    public static String getProperty(final String name) {
        return systemPropertiesMap.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, final Properties props) throws BeansException {
        super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);
        systemPropertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (final Object key : props.keySet()) {
            final String keyStr = key.toString();
            final String valueStr = resolvePlaceholder(keyStr, props, springSystemPropertiesMode);
            systemPropertiesMap.put(keyStr, valueStr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSystemPropertiesMode(final int systemPropertiesMode) {
        super.setSystemPropertiesMode(systemPropertiesMode);
        springSystemPropertiesMode = systemPropertiesMode;
    }
```

my application-context file

```
  <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="com.test.SpringPropertiesUtil">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${config.path}/application.properties</value>
                <value>file:${config.path}/log.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 7):

Your real issue was just a typo at `@Value("${com.test.isTestEnable")` - you're missing a closing curly bracket `}` at the end of the expression

This should work completely fine:

```java
    @Value("${com.test.isTestEnable}")
    public Boolean isTestEnable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the following line

```
@Value("${com.test.isTestEnable")
```

to

```
@Value("#{new Boolean('${com.test.isTestEnable}')}")
```

OR

```
@Value("#{T(Boolean).parseBoolean('${com.test.isTestEnable}')}")
```

Comment: Thanks "@Value("#{new Boolean('${com.test.isTestEnable}')}")" that's what I have been using so far to make it work. Although I have other projects where it works fine without new Boolean with above config. May be I am missing some other config or initialisation?

Comment: I don't think so...it is about casting property value to Boolean. Just check there ,may be the field type is string in other projects.